# get the required data from table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the table with fields id,before_value,after_value.I have the array value for parent_id ('11')

I want to get the value in below constraints

1. `before value is OIN` and `after value is MGL`
2. `after value is MGL` and `before value is not OIN` and `parent id is in my array ('11','18');`

3  `before value is MGL` and `after value is MQL`

[image]

I have tried as

```
$audit_table_result=$audit_table_result->orWhere(function ($query) use ($meeting_ids){
            return $query->where('after_value_string','=','MGL')->whereNotIn('before_value_string',['OIB'])->whereIn('parent_id',['11','18']);
             })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('before_value_string','=','MGL')
           ->where('after_value_string','=','MQL');
             })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('before_value_string','=','OIB')
           ->where('after_value_string','=','MGL');
             })->where('parent_id',$added_id)   
            ->get();
```

I expected to get the id `1,3,4,5`
but I'm getting `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Answer (score 0):

```
$audit_table_result->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('before_value', 'OIN')->where('after_value', 'MGL');
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($meeting_ids) {
    return $query->where('before_value', '!=', 'OIN')->where('after_value', 'MGL')->whereIn('parent_id', $meeting_ids);
})
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('before_value', 'MGL')->where('after_value', 'MQL');
})
->get();
```